# При выполнении функции выходит неизвестное число и не доходит до конца

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Есть простая функция, которая должна выводить счетчик чисел, само число, и останавливаться когда оно доходит до нуля, однако после первого числа откуда-то берется 32759, и останавливается на втором элементе. Я попросил другого человека запустить этот код, и у него он работал корректно.
Пользуюсь VS 2022 года, может ли в этом быть проблема?

```
void VarArgs(int arg1, ...)
{
    int num = 0;
    int* p = &arg1;
    while (*p != 0)
    {
        cout << "Arg " << num << ": " << *p << endl;;
        p++; 
        num++;
    }
    cout << "Total - " << num << endl;
}

int nN1=5, nN2=11, nN3=4, nN4=7, nN5=-1;
VarArgs(nN1,nN2,nN3,nN4,nN5,0);
```

Comment: Не используйте код, который дает UB, и не получите это самое неопределенное поведение. Работать с переменным количеством аргументов надо только одним способом: через `stdarg.h`.

Comment: Способ передачи аргументов в функцию зависит от компилятора и компьютерной архитектуры. Очевидно, что в вашем случае компилятор не укладывает параметры функции в стек, растущий к младшим адресам в обратном порядке (только в этом случае первый параметр окажется в памяти так, как ожидает ваша функция)

Comment: Странно вы используете параметры! int arg1 как число уже пришло в стек функции. И вы берёте указатель на это число!? Теоретически нужно сам параметр делать ссылкой (int *arg1,...) Тогда в вашу функцию (в её стек) не будет копироваться число int arg1 а будет приходить готовый указатель на место в памяти, где лежит arg1. В основном такой параметр именуют P в первом символе имени параметра, типа int *Parg1, и тогда понятно что это указатель пришел. И в функции его и использовать, ну или тратить еще память для выделения своего, указывающего туда-же, как в вашем случае.

Comment: Ваш int* p = &arg1; указывает на число в стеке функции. И делая p++; вы рассчитываете что в стеке лежит следующий параметр? Но оно не так =) Там по смещению (int) p++ лежит 32759. А ваш arg2 лежит в другом месте :) А в коде нет p=&arg2 !
Для проверки сравните или выведите адрес p++ и &arg2, и скорее всего это будут разные адреса.